# Replaced Samba3 server with Synology: old VB6 program cannot create files

Tags: samba, vb6

I've replaced a Samba3 server with a Synology DS218 and an old program written in VB6 cannot create new files on the share anymore. The VB exe runs on some XP machines, and the share is mapped to the same drive letter as before.

What is weird: files can be opened and modified by the software (there's an mdb database working perfectly), but when it attempts to create a new one it fails. The file gets created but program crashes as soon as tries to write/save to it.

Any hint on what it could be is welcome.

The old smb3 config is this:

```
[global]
   workgroup = GASATI
   hosts allow = 192.168.0.0/24
   null passwords = yes
   create mask = 0755
   local master = no
   os level = 20
   guest account = socio
   server string = %h server
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   security = share
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = no
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
[data]
   comment = Data
   path = /home/data
   public = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest only = yes
   browsable = yes
   writable = yes
   printable = no
```

while the one created automatically by DSM on the Synology:

```
root@syno:~# cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
    printcap name=cups
    winbind enum groups=yes
    include=/var/tmp/nginx/smb.netbios.aliases.conf
    security=user
    local master=no
    realm=*
    passdb backend=smbpasswd
    printing=cups
    max protocol=SMB2
    winbind enum users=yes
    load printers=yes
    workgroup=WORKGROUP
root@syno:~# cat /etc/samba/smb.share.conf
[data]
    recycle bin admin only=yes
    ftp disable modify=no
    ftp disable download=no
    write list=nobody,nobody
    browseable=yes
    mediaindex=no
    hide unreadable=no
    win share=yes
    enable recycle bin=yes
    invalid users=nobody,nobody
    read list=nobody,nobody
    ftp disable list=no
    edit synoacl=yes
    valid users=nobody,nobody
    writeable=yes
    guest ok=yes
    path=/volume1/data
    skip smb perm=yes
    comment="Condivisione software"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one might have guessed it was a *software* problem: unexpectedly, the VB6 program tried to access the share directly without password, leading to unexpected behaviour.

According to the programmer the source uses only relative paths, and again the share was mapped to a local drive in Win7. It's new to him as well that it tried to perform actions directly on the share.

I had to enable guest account on the Synology and allowing guest to access the share. This allowed the program to work.